# G Suite App : Continue button on the "Domain wide install" stop working

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, gsuite-addons

I have configured a G Suite market place application and it's still in the test level. After filling the configuration page of the market application I got a button named "Integrate with Google" in the top of the Marketplace SDK configuration page

[image]

After clicking the button I get a pop up with the title "Domain wide install" there we have the "Continue" button. Previously that button redirected users to the consent screen, but it doesn't redirect to anything now. I did not change anything in the configuration so I guess this is probably a change from Google side.

[image]

Please let me know what the issue is?

Comment: Same issue here, not working, succeeded few times in Firefox and in Edge, but in general continue button is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open Issue on Google's Issue tracker about this at:

https://issuetracker.google.com/153243016

You should add a start next to the issue number, for it to get more visibility.

Comment: Done, I'll also track the issue from there. Thanks Aerials.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you can try reaching out to G Suite support here: https://gsuite.google.com/support/

Comment: Issue is resolved now. It was an issue from google.